# Getting NullReferenceException, even when using a n-1 for last row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I am running into a problem that's driving me nuts,...lol.
I am getting a null value returned, and thus a NullReferenceException, during runtime.

I am trying to get the content of the first column in the last row of my datagridview.
I am using RowCount-1, since datagridview is like an array, which has a last value of n-1 (index is from 0 to n-1).

I have also debugged it, and in the trace, it gets the right rowindex for the last row in the datagridview, but somehow it gets a null for that particular cell value, which is weird, since that has a value in the DB.

Here is my code:

```
string newitemID = this.dataGridView_DataEntry.Rows[this.dataGridView_DataEntry.RowCount - 1].Cells["itemID"].Value.ToString();
```

Any help/input on what i'm over looking would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is not `Cells["itemID"]` that's null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You are right, Cells["itemID"] is whats returning a null.

My question then, is how is that so?, since there is a column named "itemID", and there is a value in that row, for that particular cell/column.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to split the code in multiple lines just to see which part of your statement throws the NullReferenceException

```
var row =this.dataGridView_DataEntry.Rows[this.dataGridView_DataEntry.RowCount - 1];
```

If there is no exception in above line then it means the last row is present.

```
var column = row.Cells["itemID"];
```

If there is any exception here then probably there is no cell called "itemID".

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, after changing the line as you suggested to this:
var row = this.dataGridView_DataEntry.Rows[this.dataGridView_DataEntry.RowCount - 1];
string newitemID = row.Cells["itemID"].Value.ToString();


it appears that row.Cells["itemID"].Value.ToString(); is returning a null

When i viewed more details in the exception thrown in VS, its says "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: So i think there no column called itemID i guess, is your issue resolved now?

Comment: there is a column called itemID. Issue is still not solved unfortunately.

What i found weird is that when i changed it to 'RowCount -2', to see if it can get the value of the itemID of the 2nd to last item in the datagridview, it worked.